# React Native Picker Display Current Month

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-picker-select

I am using [React Native Picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker) to display the list of month numbers.

I am trying to show the current month when loading the picker (in this case `02 (February)`).

But, when loading the screen it always displays `01`(January) instead of `02`(February).

> Another thing is that even though label shows `01`(January), the picker value however remains
> as `02`(February).

*It would be really helpful if someone could solve this issue.*

**Here's the code snippet provided below:**

```
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    
    
    export default class AdminNews extends Component {
    
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          date: {
            month: currentMonth,
          },
        }
      }
    
    
      renderMonthPickerItem() {
        //this shows the currentMonth but it overlaps with the other pickerItems.
        //which means it shows currentMonth 02 two times
        // let pickers = [
        //   <Picker.Item
        //     label={currentMonth.toString().padStart(2, '0')}
        //     value={currentMonth.toString()}
        //     key={currentMonth} />
        // ];
        let pickers = [];
    
        for (let month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
          pickers.push(
            <Picker.Item label={month.toString().padStart(2, '0')} value={month.toString()} key={month} />
          );
        }
    
        return pickers;
      }
    
    
      renderMonth() {
        return (
          <>
            <View><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'grey' }}>Month:</Text></View>
            <View style={{ marginVertical: 1 }} />
            <View style={{ borderRadius: 5, elevation: 3, backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA' }}>
              <Picker
                mode="dropdown"
                selectedValue={this.state.date.month}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                  this.setState({
                    date: {
                      ...this.state.date,
                      month: itemValue
                    }
                  });
    
                  this.apiNews();
                }}
              >
                {this.renderMonthPickerItem()}
              </Picker>
            </View>
          </>
        );
      }


       render(){ return( ***other code*** ); }
    };
```

**Screenshot:**

When calling the api it takes the value of `month` `02` but on picker it shows `month` `01`.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: IF you are not using Moment.js i would suggest to look into moment.js it makes your live easier when handling date also provides nice formatting and functions ;)

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that the keys and values are not the same, string and integer:
`<Picker.Item ... value={month.toString()} key={month} />`
In this case you should handle that in the onValueChange method

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir handling inside onValueChange is where I am stuck. Could you provide an example on how I might be able to show the current Month? Other than that everything seems to work fine.

Comment: I would store `month` as an integer in my state, why convert it to string at all? `<Picker.Item ... value={month.toString()} ... />` to `<Picker.Item ... value={month} ... />`. If you need to pass a string value to your api, than do the conversion there